# Clebsch-Gordan coefficients for the Kronecker product of 2-dimensional irreducible representations of $S_3$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

How to calculate the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.
I have computed the 2 dimensional irreducible representations of $S_3$:
$$ D^{(2)}(e)=I_{2},D^{(2)}(a)= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & -1 \\
\end{array}\right), D^{(2)}(\alpha)= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
 \right)
 $$

Now, I would like to calculate the Clebsch-Gordan decomposition of the Kronecker product of this 2 dimensional representation with itself, that is:
$$ D^{2\otimes 2}=\bigoplus_{l=1}^{3}a_{l} D^{(l)} $$ 
I calculated the coefficients using orthogonalization relations :
$$ D^{2\otimes 2}=D^{(1)}\oplus D^{(1')} \oplus D^{(2)} $$ 
Where 1 and 1' represent the trivial and alternating representations respectively.

This is what I've tried:

Take, for example, $D^{2\otimes 2}(a) $ :
$$ \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & -1 & 0  \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\
\end{array} \right) $$

It can be seen that this matrix is not block diagonal. So, the task is to find a basis for which this matrix becomes block diagonal, because of Clebsch-Gordan . How can I find such basis?.

I don't know if this is the best method to tackle this problem. So, it would be nice if you can provide **alternative methods** to compute the Clebschs.

Any help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I learn Clebsch-Gordan coefficients using [character theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_theory). For any representation $V$ of group $G$,
you can define its character, i.e. a group homomorphism $\chi_V:G\to \mathbf{C}$
such that $\chi_V(g)=\text{trace}(g)$.

**Class function.** A function $f:G\to \mathbf{C}$ is a class function if 
it is constant under conjugacy class, i.e. $f(g)=f(hgh^{-1})$ for all $h,g\in G$.
Denote $C(G)$ be the vector space of all class functions on $G$. 
Note that $\chi_V$ is also a class function (why?).

One can define a Hermitian inner product on $C(G)$ by (check this) 
$$ \langle f,g\rangle = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{s\in G}f(s)\overline{g(s)} $$
The whole point is that characters of all irreducible reprsentations of $G$
(irreducible characters for short) form an orthonormal basis of $C(G)$.
This implies that two representation $V,W$ are isomorphic iff their 
characters $\chi_V=\chi_W$.

From [properties of characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_theory#Arithmetic_properties), we find if $D^{2\otimes 2}
=a D^1\oplus bD^{1'}\oplus cD^{2}$ then its corresponding 
character $\chi_{2\otimes 2}=a\chi_1+b\chi_{1'}+c\chi_2$. Due to 
orthogonal relation, we find $a= \langle \chi_{2\otimes 2},\chi_1\rangle,
b=\langle  \chi_{2\otimes 2},\chi_1'\rangle, c= \langle \chi_{2\otimes 2},\chi_2\rangle$. Also from property of characters, we know 
$\chi_{2\otimes 2}=(\chi_2)^2$. Hence, to find $a,b,c$, it suffices to 
find irreducible characters $\chi_1,\chi_1',\chi_2$.

Note these characters are class functions, i.e. they are constant under 
conjugacy classes so we only need to find their value under each
conjugacy class of $S_3$. I think you can continue from here
knowing the definition of characters and you also know all $D^1,D^{1'},D^2$.

The final answer is $D^{2\otimes 2}=D^1\oplus D^{1'}\oplus D^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One question: Then the $a_{l} $ are the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients?. I thought they were related to a change of base.

Comment: @IEDCPHY From what I know from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/47896/58951, yes.